# Result of Ping between two devices connected to the same router is different

Tags: networking, ping

For my research, i have 2 devices (Raspberry Pi and Laptop) connected to same router by cable and running speedtest by ookla software to the same server with ping, download speed, upload speed parameters.

in my experiment, the ping result between Raspberry Pi and laptop has differences around 20ms (ex. laptop 4ms raspberry 24ms) but the download and upload speed not much different.

Why only latency that have different result? which components on the device that affect the latency? . It is possible that I might misunderstand a few concepts here. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: 20ms difference is an eternity on a home network's router's LAN interface _(I've never had a result >2ms, it's usually <1ms)_ - does the same occur when swapping the ethernet ports on the router _(PC's to Pi's port, Pi's to PC's - rules out the router)_. How long is the ethernet cable to the Pi and does the same occur with a CAT5e and CAT6 cable that's <10ft _(the shorter the better for troubleshooting)_? If that results in an improvement, try with a longer cable, as there's only a handful of potential causes _(cable type/length/gauge, Pi's voltage/current over ethernet, Pi's software, etc.)_

Answer (score -1):

Latency is like delay from one point to another.

There are several factors to it:

- Each cable is a different CAT rating (CAT rating determined your cable wire size gauge, t could be a factor).
- The cable length is different.
- The Ethernet Chip on your Raspberry Pi is different, check it. (even different date or batch could make it different ping but highly unlikely)
- Your CPU loading is different on each Raspberry, this could be factoring in your latency.

But 2 reasons from the top is the most occurs.

Comment: im using CAT 5E cable with same length and same connector type.

so, does the CPU really affect the ping result?

Comment: it does, but very little effect to it

Comment: alright then thank you so much

Comment: Don't forget that many RPi models have a _USB-attached_ Ethernet chip, which will have different properties than PCI-attached ones on most other computers. (Though I still don't see how all of this could add up to 20 ms, but it's possible.)

Comment: As long as the cable is in-spec for whatever flavor of Ethernet you're running on it, the cable quality doesn't affect latency. For example, gigabit Ethernet (1000BASE-T) requires Cat 5 or better. So if OP's cable complies with Cat 5 or better, it's all the same, latency-wise. Also, the max supported run of an Ethernet cable is 100m, and signals traverse that in about 333 nanoseconds. So the maximum latency that cable length can add is 3-4 *orders of magnitude* too small to show up in ping times.

Comment: @spiff apparently it does. because when i bought different CAT rating for my school the latency is different on the same length.